# warning MSB3391: <DLL> does not contain any types that can be unregistered for COM Interop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com-interop, typelib, comvisible

I've made a simple C# DLL (that's part of a much larger project) using VS2005.  I need to use the DLL in Excel via VBA code so I am using COM Interop on the assembly.  I am **trying to make the build process automatically generate the necessary TLB file** so that I don't need to go to the command line and use regasm after every build.

My problem is that although the DLL compiles and builds fine, it does not generate a TLB file.  Instead, the error in the title prints out in the output box.

I've gotten other DLLs to build TLB files by going to the project's properties in VS2005 -> Build -> Output -> Check *"Register for COM interop"*.  Also I have *[assembly: ComVisible(true)] in the AssemblyInfo.cs*.

Here's the summary of the source for the problem DLL and the DLL that it references for a return type:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using SymbolTable;

namespace ProblemLibrary
{
    public class Foo
    {    
        public Foo(string filename)
        {
            ...
        }

        // method to read a text file into a SymbolTable
        public SymbolTable BuildDataSet(string[] selected)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a summary of SymbolTable.dll.  It holds a return type that ProblemLibrary uses.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SymbolTable
{
    public class SymbolTable
    {
        readonly Dictionary<SymbolInfoStub, string> _symbols = new Dictionary<SymbolInfoStub, string>();

       /*methods that interact with Dictionary snipped*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the COM interop? I don't see any COM there. Do you want to access the C# Assembly via COM later?

Comment: Yes, I need to use this DLL in Excel VBA.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. You need to have ctor without any params.
2. You should have [GuidAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute.aspx) and [ProgIdAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.progidattribute.aspx) around the classes.
3. Its better to mark the assembly as ComVisible(false) and mark explicitly the classes that need export.
4. Use interfaces for your classes.
5. Make sure the you have GuidAttribute in the assembly level.

   ```
   [Guid("<PUT-GUID-HERE-1>")]
   [ComVisible(true)]
   interface IFoo
   {
       void DoFoo();
   }

   [Guid("<PUT-GUID-HERE-2>")]
   [ComVisible(true)]
   [ProgId("ProgId.Foo")]
   class Foo : IFoo
   {
       public void DoFoo()
       {
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Awesome, the Constructor without any parameters did the trick.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Empty Constructor. That's been bugging me forever! Thanks.

Comment: That's a bit dumb for a class which should also be usable in typical .NET manner. Imagine a specific file format class, which has a constructor accepting a file name - typical way to instantiate it in .NET. Now just to make that class COM visible, I remove the constructor and I'd have to call a static "Load" method for that in .NET, and then still have a public instance / non-static "Load" method to create it just for COM. That looks a bit dirty, doesn't it?

Comment: Note: For me, the error still occurs until I make the interface and class PUBLIC. Also note that [ProgID] is optional, and [Guid] can be auto-generated.

Answer (score 4):

In the AssemblyInfo.cs file, make sure you have the following:

```
// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
```

**UPDATE:**

Read: [How can I make use of .NET objects from within Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179452/how-can-i-make-use-of-net-objects-from-within-excel-vba)

Which links to:
http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I wrote in my description that I already have that.

Comment: I've gotten other C# DLLs to work in COM before.  Though the links didn't help me with my issue, I did learn about the link between COM client intellisense and [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)] in C# from them.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

I saw a similar problem. I got an error like:

> warning MSB3391: does not contain any
>   types that can be unregistered for COM
>   Interop.

I followed all the rules (ComVisible, etc.) but nothing worked.

**Solution:** I had to put something in the default constructor so that it would not be optimized away. The moment I had something there, the registration finished with no message and the component was visible in the registry.

**Interesting note:** a friend of mine managed to register the original DLL with the empty default constructor on his machine (64-bit Windows-7, VS2008-Professional, like mine). However, his REGASM.EXE was:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\regasm.exe

while mine was:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe

So it could be some difference between versions of the .NET framework - maybe the later version is optimizing too much and the REGASM does not account for that.

Comment: I also got this warning, the register warning went away after adding comvisible but the unregister did not until i put a dummy step in the constructor.