# My C# COM Library Isn't Working Right; Can't Instantiate The Class and a Method Appears As a Property

Tags: c#, vba, com

I'm writing a COM DLL in C# to handle the import and export of X.12 format documents, so I would be able to use it in an Access database and a custom program for handling EDI with my company. I've gotten a DLL to compile but with disappointing results, and I'm wondering if I'm missing something; COM "from scratch" is new ground to me (I've made a ribbon for Excel before but a wizard handled all of that).

I've read [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3fd4a20) and came across [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853553/warning-msb3391-dll-does-not-contain-any-types-that-can-be-unregistered-for-co) to get my DLL and TLB to compile and register. This is the skeleton of my X12Segment class and the interface for COM visibility:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace X12
{
    [Guid("28A76274-05EE-45B2-A8EF-ADD5A5B351DE"),
    ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IX12Segment
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        string SegmentType { get; set; }
        [DispId(2)]
        string[] Fields { get; set; }
        [DispId(3)]
        char FieldDelimiter { get; set; }
        [DispId(4)]
        char SegmentDelimiter { get; set; }
        [DispId(5)]
        string ToString(char sep, char eol);
        [DispId(6)]
        string ToString();
        [DispId(7)]
        Type GetFieldEnum();
    }

    [Guid("B321599A-E5EC-4510-A021-E9A8B4D6293E"),
    ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
    ComVisible(true)]
    public class X12Segment : IX12Segment
    {
        private string _type;

        protected ArrayList _fields;
        protected short _minFields = -1;
        protected short _maxFields = -1;
        protected short[][] _fieldSizes = { new short[] { -1, -1 } };
        protected char _sep;
        protected char _eol;

        public enum Field { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new X.12 segment of the supplied type,
        /// optionally with a supplied number of fields or
        /// values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="segType">The type of segment (eg "ISA", "GS")</param>
        /// <param name="fields">Each string is a field
        /// within the segment</param>
        public X12Segment(string segType, params string[] fields)
            : this(segType)
        {
            //Do cool stuff
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new X.12 segment from a string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="segType">The type of segment (eg "ISA", "GS")</param>
        /// <param name="segment">The string to parse</param>
        public X12Segment(string segType, string segment)
            : this(segType)
        {
            //Do cool stuff
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new X.12 segment of the supplied type,
        /// optionally with a supplied number of fields or
        /// values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="segType">The type of segment (eg "ISA", "GS")</param>
        /// <param name="fieldCount">The number of fields
        /// in this segment</param>
        public X12Segment(string segType, int fieldCount) : this(segType)
        {
            //Do cool stuff
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new X.12 segment of the supplied type,
        /// optionally with a supplied number of fields or
        /// values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="segType">The type of segment (eg "ISA", "GS")</param>
        public X12Segment(string segType) : this()
        {
            //Do cool stuff
        }

        public X12Segment()
        {
            //Do cool stuff
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the segment type.
        /// </summary>
        public string SegmentType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets all of the fields in the segment,
        /// in the form of an array of strings.
        /// </summary>
        public string[] Fields
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the character used to seperate fields in the segment.
        /// </summary>
        public char FieldDelimiter
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the character denoting the end of the segment.
        /// </summary>
        public char SegmentDelimiter
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates an X.12 formatted segment.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sep">The field delimiter to use.</param>
        /// <param name="eol">The segment delimiter to use.</param>
        /// <returns>An X.12 formatted string.</returns>
        public string ToString(char sep, char eol)
        {
            //Do cool stuff
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates an X.12 formatted segment.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An X.12 formatted string.</returns>
        public override string ToString()
        {
            //Do cool stuff
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the Type associated with the Field enumeration of this object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A System.Type of this object's Field enumeration.</returns>
        public virtual Type GetFieldEnum()
        {
            //Do cool stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I open up VBA and add the reference, the class shows up in IntelliSense. However, when I Dim a variable with the X12Segment type, then put in the dot operator, the IntelliSense window that pops up shows me that ToString() is a property, not a method. Also, ToString's overload shows up as ToString_2. When I attempt `Set seg = New X12Segment`, VBA tells me that it's an invalid use of the New keyword.

What am I missing here?

### Update

I've revised my code as per the comments and answer below, and I have solutions for `New` not working and my ToString overload appearing funky in IntelliSense. A new problem arises, though; trying to access Fields gives me errors. `seg.Fields = someStringArray` gets me an error saying "Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic".

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Those ARE properties, even in your C# code.

Comment: Whup. For some reason I thought I had more than that. But either way, ToString is a method and it shows up as a property. And I can't instantiate my X12Segment in VBA.

Comment: Method overloading isn't valid in COM (as well as some other technologies - see WCF, web services).  That's why your ToString() / ToString_2() shows up like that - the compiler protected you from that implementation detail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [ComVisible] class must have a parameterless constructor.  COM doesn't have a mechanism to pass arguments to a constructor.  You provided only constructors that take arguments which is why VBA doesn't let you use the New keyword.

COM also doesn't support method overloading.  You need to give the methods distinct names.  If you don't then the type library exporter will take care of it automatically.  Thus ToString_2().

Comment: There is a noarg ctor in there, turns out VBA was being picky as hell and wanted me to put the namespace as well as the class; just figured that out from [this post on xtremevbtalk](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=226000).

And thanks to you and GalacticCowboy for explaining that overloads don't work! I still don't get why ToString() is being shown as a property, though, even after removing the overload.

Comment: Well, the VBA syntax for calling a function that takes no arguments and using a property getter is the same.  So it may just look like a property.