# C# COM Object In VBA: Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic

Tags: c#, vba, com

Coming off of [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012736/my-c-com-library-isnt-working-right-cant-instantiate-the-class-and-a-method-a) with a new problem: I get the titular error when attempting to access my X12Segment's Fields property.

I came across [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965767/function-or-interface-marked-as-restricted-or-the-function-uses-an-automation-ty) and took the initiative to get the IDL for my X12 type library. Also attached is the declaration of the Fields property in my interface, and its implementation; what's causing this error?

```idl
// Generated .IDL file (by the OLE/COM Object Viewer)
// 
// typelib filename: <could not determine filename>

[
  uuid(C0634D32-97A5-413A-8FC8-D6E0F4571F42),
  version(1.0),
  custom(90883F05-3D28-11D2-8F17-00A0C9A6186D, "X12, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")

]
library X12
{
    // TLib :     // TLib : mscorlib.dll : {BED7F4EA-1A96-11D2-8F08-00A0C9A6186D}
    importlib("mscorlib.tlb");
    // TLib : OLE Automation : {00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    // Forward declare all types defined in this typelib
    interface IX12Segment;

    [
      odl,
      uuid(28A76274-05EE-45B2-A8EF-ADD5A5B351DE),
      version(1.0),
      dual,
      oleautomation,
      custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "X12.IX12Segment")    

    ]
    interface IX12Segment : IDispatch {
        [id(0x00000001), propget]
        HRESULT SegmentType([out, retval] BSTR* pRetVal);
        [id(0x00000001), propput]
        HRESULT SegmentType([in] BSTR pRetVal);
        [id(0x00000002), propget]
        HRESULT Fields([out, retval] SAFEARRAY(BSTR)* pRetVal);
        [id(0x00000002), propput]
        HRESULT Fields([in] SAFEARRAY(BSTR) pRetVal);
        [id(0x00000003), propget]
        HRESULT FieldDelimiter([out, retval] BSTR* pRetVal);
        [id(0x00000003), propput]
        HRESULT FieldDelimiter([in] BSTR pRetVal);
        [id(0x00000004), propget]
        HRESULT SegmentDelimiter([out, retval] BSTR* pRetVal);
        [id(0x00000004), propput]
        HRESULT SegmentDelimiter([in] BSTR pRetVal);
        [id(0x00000005), propget,
          custom(54FC8F55-38DE-4703-9C4E-250351302B1C, 1)]
        HRESULT ToString([out, retval] BSTR* pRetVal);
        [id(0x00000006)]
        HRESULT GetFieldEnum([out, retval] _Type** pRetVal);
    };

    [
      uuid(B321599A-E5EC-4510-A021-E9A8B4D6293E),
      version(1.0),
      custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "X12.X12Segment")
    ]
    coclass X12Segment {
        interface _Object;
        [default] interface IX12Segment;
    };
};
```

```cs
[Guid("28A76274-05EE-45B2-A8EF-ADD5A5B351DE"),
ComVisible(true)]
public interface IX12Segment
{
    //More stuff goes here
    [DispId(2)]
    string[] Fields { get; set; }
    //More stuff goes here
}

[Guid("B321599A-E5EC-4510-A021-E9A8B4D6293E"),
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
ComVisible(true)]
public class X12Segment : IX12Segment
{
    protected ArrayList _fields;
    protected short _minFields = -1;
    protected short _maxFields = -1;
    protected short[][] _fieldSizes = { new short[] { -1, -1 } };

    //More stuff goes here

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets all of the fields in the segment,
    /// in the form of an array of strings.
    /// </summary>
    public string[] Fields
    {
        get
        {
            string[] o = new string[_fields.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < o.Length; i++)
            {
                o[i] = _fields[i].ToString();
            }
            return o;
        }
        set
        {
            ArrayList newFields = new ArrayList(value.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
                if (_fieldSizes[0][0] == -1 || value[i].Length <= _fieldSizes[i][1])
                    newFields.Add(value[i].ToCharArray());
                else
                    throw new Exception("Attempt to store a value longer than the possible field size: \""
                        + value[i] + "\" is larger than " + _fieldSizes[i] + " characters long.");
        }
    }

    //More stuff goes here
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same thing.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research on the matter after coming back to work off the weekend, and apparently VBA not getting along with .NET is the issue. According to [this MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327084) and also stated in [this DevX forum thread](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=56278), it seems it doesn't like method parameters with an array passed by reference and wants them passed by value instead. There's a workaround for VB.NET code in that MSDN article where you simply tell it to pass the set value by value,  but defining parameters for accessors in C# doesn't seem to be possible.

My solution was to make the Fields property be read-only, and have seperate methods for setting either a single element or the whole shebang.

```cs
//Added these to the interface.
[DispId(aNumber)]
void SetField(int index, string value);
[DispId(aNumber)]
void SetFields(ref string[] fields);

//Added these two methods to the class,
//and removed the set accessor from the Fields property

/// <summary>
/// Set a field at the given index with a given value.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="index">Zero-based index of the field to set.</param>
/// <param name="value">The value to set the field with.</param>
public void SetField(int index, string value)
{
    if (_fieldSizes[0][0] == -1 ||
            (value.Length > _fieldSizes[index][0] && value.Length < _fieldSizes[index][1]))
        _fields[index] = value.ToCharArray();
    else
        throw new ArgumentException("value", "Attempt to set a field with a value longer or shorter than the expected length.");
}

/// <summary>
/// Sets all the fields with the values in an array.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fields">An array of strings containing the values.</param>
public void SetFields(ref string[] fields)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
        SetField(i, fields[i]);
}
```