# Looking for alternatives to 32-bit only Microsoft Common Controls (ListView)

Tags: .net, excel, vba, listview, 64-bit

I have a legacy application developed in VBA/Excel which uses ListView controls. Unfortunately, it looks like [these controls can't be used with 64-bit versions of Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831.aspx):

> Native 64-bit processes in Office 2010 cannot load 32-bit binaries. This includes the common controls of MSComCtl [such as ListViews]. **An alternative must be found for existing Microsoft Office VBA solutions that utilize these controls when the code is migrated to 64-bit Office 2010.**

I need to migrate that legacy application to Excel 2010/13 x64. The process is mostly painless except for those `ListView` controls.

**What are my main options to replace the `ListView` control and which would be the most effective (from a time&difficulty to implement perspective)?**

Notes:

- This issue has been raised on [MS forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/excel/thread/2e4d01a1-5f56-415d-9e2d-b3bef8e5f08d) but no practical answer has been given.
- adding `.net` tag as I suspect some solutions could come from there.

---

To make it clearer, here is a snapshot of the Excel user form. The bottom part is the list view (I have hidden confidential information), which has sortable column, allows the user to select multiple, non-consecutive, lines.

[image]

Comment: Which ListView capabilities are you using? Column headers? Groups? How far would an owner-drawn ListBox get you instead?

Comment: @shambulator Mostly: headers, columns sorting, multi-line selection, column auto-sizing.

Comment: Are the ListViews in UserForms or directly in the worksheets? If the latter, what about using Excel tables (i.e. `ListObjects`) - and add some individual behavior with events (e.g. to multi-select rows, sort columns)?

Comment: @PeterAlbert They are in Forms which enables the user to have them in front of them while doing their stuff on the spreadsheet.

Comment: Bugger! Can share some kind of disguised screenshot of a typical form+spreadsheet?

Comment: Have you tried using a multicolumn listbox instead of listview?

Comment: @SiddharthRout No I have not - not sure if it can achieve the same, in particular the sorting and multi-select parts (I don't think I have ever used multicolumn listboxes).

Comment: No unfortunately it won't let you do those. I was referring in terms of displaying the data.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Now I could always put some clickable areas at the top of the columns and repopulate the list box manually when required but I was trying to avoid re-coding the whole ListView object myself!

Comment: That would be unpractical... + 1 BTW for a good question :)

Comment: @PeterAlbert I have added a snapshot.

Comment: Looking at the snapshot, I do not see anything that cannot be done with a native Excel table (i.e. ListObject)! And if you want to have this information displayed next to another worksheet, check out the technique provided here: http://superuser.com/questions/554507/excel-2010-freeze-column-to-both-horizontal-and-vertical-scroll/554969#554969

Comment: @PeterAlbert can one include a listobject in a form?

Comment: No, you can't, as the ListObject is using the normal worksheet grid (at least not to my knowledge, and even if so, most likely not on 64bit). That's why I'd suggest to replace the UserForm with another Excel window that's just left or top of the main window...

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this issue?  I'm trying to write a COM wrapper for the ListView control as well, but I don't really write C# much and I'm having issues displaying the actual control in a form.

Comment: Unfortunately not - if you find anything, feel free to share!

Answer (score 10):

One thing that is theoretically possible would be to write your display code as a .Net assembly and access that via COM from your VBA code (see for example [How can I make use of .NET objects from within Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179452/how-can-i-make-use-of-net-objects-from-within-excel-vba) as a starting point for how to do this).

That way you can write .Net code for your controls. I haven't done that myself and am not sure how well it applies to your problem, but it looks like an option.

I just found a [short tutorial](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/) for calling .Net from Excel.

Comment: That can probably work but I'm not very familiar witn .net (I generally use Java) and I'm not sure how that example can be transposed to show a complex object in a user form.

Comment: After I learned how to use Visual Studio and .NET, I completely abandoned VBA and started using .NET interop.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of any solution here. However, JKP has developed [a native TreeView in VBA with Userforms only](http://jkp-ads.com/articles/treeview.asp) to replace the TreeView - which works fine under 64bit.

Though labour-intense you could consider adopting it to a ListView control...

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still interested I managed to put something together (4 years ago).  I remember it being a very painful process because the process to create COM interfaces over the years changed and there were a few different methods/references. Also, because of the way COM works, it needs to use dual Interfaces.  I didn't expose all of the properties/events, but I did the main ones that you'll probably need.  The code was written in C# with VS2010; I didn't test if the code still compiles, either way you should be able to use the .DLL in the Bin folder if you Register the library (see Reg.bat).  It shows up as "[64bit COM Interface v1.2 for .Net Common Controls](https://github.com/Profex13/ListView64)" under Tool->References.

Answer (score -1):

You need to delete and then re-register the control and it will work fine.  Use RegSvr32 to re-register the control.

See this link for more info: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/listview-issue-in-access-2010/d0b6f86a-1d9c-4d7f-8566-b80a10bb67c6

Comment: Have you tried it? I think RegSvr32 in the `SysWow64` folder (as detailed in your link) can only register 32 bit libraries. And 32 bit libraries are not available in Excel x64.

Comment: My bad, I missed that part about it being for 32 bit somehow.  All my searches turned up people having to create their own control, and no one seemed too eager to post their results.