# What is the 32 / 64bit safe ListView substitute?

Tags: excel, 32bit-64bit, vba

ListView and all other controls from MSComCtl and MSComCt2  are not available in 64bit office. [Details are here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831.aspx#odc_office2010_Compatibility32bit64bit_ActiveXControlCOMAddinCompatibility). But I have Excel VBA macros that use ListView and ProgressBar.

Is there a safe alternative? One that would work in Excel 2010 and 2013, both 32 and 64bit? For ScrollBar I can hack around, but for ListView I really need "normal" control, one where I can just define columns and then add entries.

Comment: Have you tried to replace with [Common Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775493(v=vs.85).aspx)?  Have a look at the [Control Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773169(v=vs.85).aspx). Specifically the [List View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774737(v=vs.85).aspx) control, and the [How to use List View Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774736(v=vs.85).aspx) entry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for alternatives to 32-bit only Microsoft Common Controls (ListView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792410/looking-for-alternatives-to-32-bit-only-microsoft-common-controls-listview)