# How can you start the TreeView in VBA Excel Userforms without any selections?

Tags: vba, excel, treeview

As can be seen in the image, whenever the userform is initialized, there is a node that is initially highlighted. However, the problem with this is that, the `NodeClick` event does not fire. This will make the user confused as to why the buttons are not working. There is also no such thing as `SelectedNode` events or the like to my knowledge.

The highlighted node is shown below:
[image: Highlighted]

Userform Initialize code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Insert the Chart of Accounts Categories (hard coded) then child nodes are the input accounts
TreeView1.Nodes.Add Key:="CURRENT ASSET", Text:="CURRENT ASSET"
TreeView1.Nodes.Add Key:="CURRENT LIABILITY", Text:="CURRENT LIABILITY"
TreeView1.Nodes.Add Key:="LONG TERM LIABILITY", Text:="LONG TERM LIABILITY"
TreeView1.Nodes.Add Key:="FIXED ASSET", Text:="FIXED ASSET"
TreeView1.Nodes.Add Key:="EQUITY", Text:="EQUITY"

'Populates the TreeView from previously stored data
Total_rows_Nodes = Worksheets("Node Details").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Total_rows_Nodes
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add Worksheets("Node Details").Cells(i, 1).Text, tvwChild, Worksheets("Node Details").Cells(i, 2).Value, Worksheets("Node Details").Cells(i, 2).Text
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `TreeView1.SelectedItem = Nothing` to "deselect" anything. However that doesn't help when you do it in the `Initialize` event because when displaying the form, the first item is selected automatically if nothing is selected.

So you have to move that part to a later moment. Putting it into the `Activate` event did the trick for me:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Set TreeView1.SelectedItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Take into account that ListView seems to be supported only by 32Bit - cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792410/looking-for-alternatives-to-32-bit-only-microsoft-common-controls-listview