# ListView does not work on Report but works on Form In Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, listview

This is the situation where I'm in. I have a Form in my Microsoft Access which has one Control. This control is a ListView named lstvtest. I have populated the ListView dynamically. So when I open the Form everything is fine, I can see that the ListView has been populated successfully and I can also see the column's heading (which I have set it in the ListView setting to show the column Heading).

Now, I have a blank Report with one control. This Control is a ListView named lstvtest. I have used the exact code I used for the Form, but when I open the Report. Few things happens

1. I don't see the column heading
2. I only see one word in the ListView.

Here is my Form VBA Code:

```
Option Compare Database
Private myLV As MSComctlLib.ListView
Private li As ListItem


Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim i As Integer
    Set myLV = lstvtest.Object
    myLV.ListItems.Clear
    myLV.Appearance = cc3D
    'add some data
    For i = 0 To 30
        Set li = myLV.ListItems.Add(, "k" & i, "Test " & i)
        li.ListSubItems.Add , , "Admin " & i
        li.ListSubItems.Add , , "B " & i
    Next
    'report view
    myLV.View = 3
End Sub
```

And here is my Report VBA Code

```
Option Compare Database
Private myLV As MSComctlLib.ListView
Private li As ListItem


Private Sub Report_Load()

    Dim i As Integer
    Set myLV = lstvtest.Object
    myLV.ListItems.Clear
    myLV.Appearance = cc3D
    'add some data
    For i = 0 To 30
        Set li = myLV.ListItems.Add(, "k" & i, "Test " & i)
        li.ListSubItems.Add , , "Admin " & i
        li.ListSubItems.Add , , "B " & i
    Next
    'report view
    myLV.View = 3
End Sub
```

Here is the screenshot of the Form when its opened

[image]

and here is the screenshot for the Report when its opened
[image]

So my question how come the ListView has not been populated in the Report? Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Try putting report code in Format event of section you want listview to appear in. Why use listview?

Comment: @June7 I did place the code in the Format event still no luck. I was trying to see if I could use ListView to display report data in a table format, that is row and column. So I am just curious why it doesn't work

Comment: `Listview` is not supported in a 64 bit Office environment. Are you sure you are using a 32 bit version?

Comment: @AcsErno I am using 64bit Microsoft Access. So when you say that ListView is not supported in the 64Bit Office environment, then how come it works in My Form.

Comment: Don't really understand why a normal report with textboxes cannot produce the 'table' format output. I also wonder how this control will perform with multi-page report, if it can be made to work at all. Quite possibly it is not intended for use with a report.

Comment: @Tman Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691831(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN. The bad news is that the instabil behaviour is a typical clue of not being supported. The good news is that MS keeps supporting `Listbox` so you'd better consider that choice.

Comment: Normally, the only data control that makes sense for use on report is textbox. A listbox won't grow, so it has to be sized to fit all data that will be retrieved by it and therefore won't really work for multi-page report. I have used it only once for a report and I was confident data would fit to one page so I sized it to full height of print area.

Comment: Amendment: along with textbox - image control, chart, and checkbox are functional to display data (not interactive) on report but controls like combobox and listbox and button rarely serve a purpose on report. I can't see any advantage for a listview on report, even if it would work.

Comment: @June7 i do agree that a i could get a  table format output using the textbox. But as i mentioned before i just wanted to test the report using the ListView.  By the way i was planning it for a single page report.  You might be right that its not intended to use with a report, but the question is when i open the report how is it that the report displays the ListView with a single word.

Comment: @AcsErno that link you mentioned it talk about office 2010, But i have MS Access 2019 64Bits and the ListView works fine without any issue.

Comment: @Tman This is a 64 bit and ActiveX issue, not an MS Access issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792410/looking-for-alternatives-to-32-bit-only-microsoft-common-controls-listview

Comment: I have Access 2010 32-bit. Just tried your form code and listview doesn't display anything. No errors and control displays but there is no data. ActiveX controls in Access are known to be erratic.

Comment: @June7, thank you for trying it on Access 32 bit as i was about to ask someone to try it. Did you put the code on Format event of Section, if you did, then you wont see that one word as i posted. But if you place the code on the Load event of Report, then you will see the one word as i am seeing.

Comment: I was testing form code, not report.

Comment: ok thank you for that,  when you say you run the code and it didn't display any data, make sure to add the 3 columns in the setting of the ListView and also see in the VB editor click on Preferences to make sure you have a tick for the 'Microsoft Windows Common controls 6.0 (SP6)'. If you can't see the 'Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0(SP6), you can load it from c:\windows\system32\MSCOMCTL.OCX

Comment: Already had the library selected but setting the columns did make a difference. Works on form now. Unless going to do some special formatting, see no advantage over listbox. Report in ReportView gets the result you show, PrintPreview is worse.

Comment: Some success, I added a Subform/Subreport (named it Child0) to a blank Report and then I set the Source Object Property of Child0 to the Form which has my ListView. Now if I open the Report I can see the ListView is fully populated. But when I click on the Print Preview, the ListView is empty.